# In img tag, image dimension has been changed dynamically

Tags: html, ios, css, image

I've captured a photo from in apple iphone 5s. 
Dimension of the image is 960x1280.
Horizontal and vertical resolution is 72 dpi, Bit depth 24.

When I show the image in the img tag, the image is automatically rotated from portrait to horizontal.

But when I see the actual image, but the image is in computer in portrait mode only.

I don't know where is the issue.
I've opened in the ms paint to. I didn't get the issue.

**I really confused in this.** **I've opened the image(which is in portrait mode) in ms paint and saved again in the same portrait mode itself. Now I've showed in the img tag, now the image is showing correctly in portrait mode itself in img tag. No issue has occurred. Working perfectly. Why the ios image is dynamically changing from portrait to horizontal?. I've checked with [http://imgur.com/ ]. The same issue has occurred in this application too.**

How to resolve this?

Comment: There is issue really existing like this. I didn't find any question like this when I've searched in stackoverflow. But why I don't understand why I got the down vote?

Comment: Can you please update the reason for the down vote? That'll help me to identify my mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes when you take a photo with an iPhone it embeds orientation information in the Exif metadata. Some applications understand this, some don't (web browsers don't), so you see different results.

Saving in MS Paint or, for example, "Save for Web" in Photoshop saves the image in the correct orientation, and strips the Exif data. You can also manually rotate the image on your phone, which will actually change the pixels, rather than just the Exif data.

Comment: Thanks. You've mentioned like some applications understand this. Is there any way we can make the html to understand this one?

Comment: Can we remove Exif metadata? Is there any issue in doing that?

Comment: No issue. Exif just stores information like camera model, shutter speed, aperture. Some cameras will add location data if it's available. Nothing your web browser needs.